Movie with a man camouflaged in a wall
I know I'm gonna smack myself in the forehead when I get the answer, but...
American movie, action, some big name star, probably late 80's or early 90's.  He's being chased through a jungle or forest by an army of bad guys.  One of the bad guys is shown creeping slowly against a wall or rock face when he stops to look around.  As the camera zooms in on him (or the shot changes to a closeup), you suddenly see an eye in the wall.  Our hero has camouflaged himself, and he grabs the bad guy around the neck and stabs him.
Sound familiar?

You sure it's not Predator? When Arnie is hiding using mud he does that. But he's hiding from the predator, not human bad guys.

These are definitely bad guys.  A Chuck Norris movie, maybe?  Or one of the Rambo's?  Damn my failing memory!  :oP

I cannot believe you let your memory fail you like this, Johnny! Easy pickins! :D

@Paulster2 - No kidding!  This is what happens when you're pushing 50...  :o)

Looks like it was Rambo II, according to this post on a random website.  Note: The proof is in the photo shown, not the video linked on said website.


Duh, of course Rambo II. That scene's a classic!

@NapoleonWilson - I remember watching it on VHS and rewinding it because I couldn't believe how well it was done.  It was such a great makeup/SFX job!  20+ years later, I just couldn't remember which movie it was.  :o)
